# How to redirect from hook to another controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want redirect user in login page if is not logged

my hook HK_Login.php inside application/hooks

```
<?php

    class HK_Login
    {
        private $CI;
        public function checkLogin()
        {
            $this->CI =& get_instance();
            if($this->CI->session->userdata('ID') == '' && $this->CI->uri->segment(3) != 'login' )
            {
                redirect($this->CI->uri->segment(1) . '/secure/login');
            }

        }
    }
```

my controller Secure.php inside application/controllers

```
<?php
class Secure extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('login/index');
    }
}
```

The result is :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /web/secure/login was not found on this server.
```

My .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

A part of my config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

autoload

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'custom');
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

hook config

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => 'HK_Login',
    'function' => 'checkLogin',
    'filename' => 'HK_Login.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

This is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Why give me this error?

added in routes.php

```
$route['/secure/login'] = 'secure/login';
```

Give the same error

Comment: what is your routes look like?

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';

$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting an error because a route is not found. add this to your routes  file

```
$route['secure/login'] = 'secure/login';
```

Comment: there was a back slash at the beginning route, should not have been there. you should be good to go.

Comment: try and navigate to /web/secure/login or /web/index.php/secure/login, let me know what you get?